# C Python How to create a function inside another function as a decorator using C

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, cpython

I would like to know how to create a Python function inside another Python function using C?
Try something like this:

```c
static PyObject *func(PyObject *self, PyObject *wrap) { // METH_O
       PyObject *newfunc(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds) = { return PyObject_Call(wrap, args, kwds); }
       return newfunc;
}
```

But the compiler expects another expression. I would like to know (or some clues) to advance my project, How to create a function inside another python function using C?

Comment: You’re trying to define a **C** function inside another, which is irrelevant at best and impossible in standard C.  Why do you need to write C for this at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C does not have closures. You cannot create a C function inside another C function and give it access to local variables from the function that defined it. Even if you could, the new C function would not be directly usable as a Python function.

You *can* [write Python classes in the Python C API](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/newtypes_tutorial.html), and this is the usual way to write Python decorators in C. For example, instead of writing

```
def decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

a decorator written in C would look more like the C API equivalent of

```
class decorator:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
```

A full, detailed guide on how to create Python classes in C would be beyond the scope of this answer. See the [previously linked documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/newtypes_tutorial.html) for a tutorial, and note that the C-level hook for `__call__` is the [`tp_call` slot](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_call).

You can look at the C implementation of `functools.partial` for an example, either the [old 3.6 implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.15/Modules/_functoolsmodule.c#L12) for a simple example or [a more recent version](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.2/Modules/_functoolsmodule.c#L33) if you want to get fancy with the new [vectorcall mechanism](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0590/).